# Select top x records for each team

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I select the x most recent records per team, Home and Away?

So the below gets me the most recent games for Swansea both home and away, how do I get it for all teams?

```
    select d.date, d.hometeam, d.awayteam 
    from dump d
    where 
    d.hometeam = 'Swansea' 
    or d.awayteam ='Swansea'
    order by STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') desc limit 6
```

For an example of the data that I have. I'm using the CSV data provided at football-data.co.uk: http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1415/E0.csv

I'm using MySQL however if there is a function or Stored Procedure which you find ideal for this purpose I can use SQL Server.

**Edit:** Expected Output

```
X      | Date    | Home Team | Away Team
----------------------------------------
Swansea| 23/03/15|Swansea    |Arsenal
----------------------------------------
Swansea| 14/03/15|Man City   |Swansea
----------------------------------------
Man Utd| 14/03/15|Man Utd    |Man City
----------------------------------------
Man Utd| 14/03/15|Man Utd    |Liverpool
```

Though if you have any suggestions on how better to present it I'm open to suggestions.

Where the left is the team in question, as the above table shows 2 per team, I'm trying to get 6 per team.

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQLServer`?

Comment: Currently I'm using MySQL, but I can use SQLServer too with no problem.

Comment: Please, for the purposes of answers, pick **one**.

Comment: Okay fair enough, MySQL

Comment: That's fine. For something of this sort they're both very similar, but the approach is entirely different. Asking for two options doubles the amount of work required to answer it. It looks like you need a proper `DATE` column to handle your date field. That's a total mess and will make your query super slow.

Comment: I'm aware, I just imported a CSV. There are only 300 records in the table so it's not a massive problem. I'm just trying to create some views so I can present it on a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get most recent 6 games for all team separately
Here are the 2 things need to take care.

1. In your schema you don't have specific column for team. So first you've to get all the team using HomeTeam & AwayTeam columns.
2. 2nd thing you want to get 6 most recent games for each team. Means within the team group you've to do the ranking but mysql doesn't support ranking function. Although we've an alternative to for ranking functions.

based on my analysis here is the query. please try it.

```
SELECT
 r.homeTeamOrAwayTeam AS team
, r.date
, r.hometeam
, r.awayteam
-- , r.rank  
FROM (
SELECT
    d.date,
    d.hometeam,
    d.awayteam,
    subQuery.homeTeamOrAwayTeam,
    CASE WHEN @runningElement = subQuery.homeTeamOrAwayTeam THEN    @groupRank := (@groupRank + 1)
      ELSE  @groupRank := 1 
   END AS rank
  , CASE WHEN @runningElement = subQuery.homeTeamOrAwayTeam THEN    @runningElement := subQuery.homeTeamOrAwayTeam
      ELSE  @runningElement := subQuery.homeTeamOrAwayTeam
   END AS runnigElement
FROM
    dump d
JOIN (
  -- to get all the hometeam & awayteam in one column
    SELECT d.hometeam AS homeTeamOrAwayTeam FROM    DUMP AS d
    UNION
    SELECT d.awayteam AS homeTeamOrAwayTeam FROM    dump AS d
) AS subQuery 
     ON d.hometeam = subQuery.homeTeamOrAwayTeam OR d.awayteam = subQuery.homeTeamOrAwayTeam,
-- for ranking purpose
 (SELECT @groupRank := 1) a,
 (SELECT @runningElement := '') b
ORDER BY
    subQuery.homeTeamOrAwayTeam,
    STR_TO_DATE(d.date, '%d/%m/%Y')
) as r
-- set your criteria (e.g. if want to get only 6 results per team)
 WHERE r.rank between 1 and 6
```

Comment: Hi Raushan, great answer! However it isn't returning 6 results per team, it's returning everything. Any ideas? It seems as though rank isn't incrementing.

Comment: When I output Rank it's 0 for every row.

Comment: Hi Jezzabeanz, rank was getting incremented starting from 0 but there was some logic flaw. I updated the query. Try it now. You can try it here as well : [ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c8a0/4 ]

Comment: Hi Raushan, I've just tested it on my local machine and I'm still getting the same result as before. I'm confused since I can see it working in the Fiddle. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using this query as it is or have done any slight modification? Check whether you've included the order by clause...

Comment: Yes it's verbatim, I copied from here and I copied from the fiddle. Would the fact that I'm using MySQL 5.5 be a problem would it?

Comment: Upgraded to MySQL 5.6.x fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to GROUP BY team and date:

```
SELECT d.team, d.date, d.hometeam, d.awayteam 
FROM dump d
GROUP BY team, date
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Comment: Oh god, my mind has gone. You wouldn't believe I did SQL report writing for a living last year would you? Hah. Thanks user4035